# jquery validate not working after adding addmethod

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validate plugin. After adding addmethod for validating some fields, then simple validation used on above fields is not working. If I put my textbox below then everything is ok. Please help!

Here is an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhmBs/435/

**SOLVED:**
After googling around I found a solution. Someone posted that after removing few lines of code inside addmethod "require_from_group" everything works fine.

removed lines of code:

```
if(!$(element).data('reval')) {
        var fields = $(options[1], element.form);
        fields.data('reval', true).valid();
        fields.data('reval', false);
    }
```